# I am trying deploy GeoServer into AWS ECS Fargate mode. I tried kartoza/geoserver:latest and docker.osgeo.org/geoserver:2.25.x

Tags: geoserver, amazon-web-services

Official dockerfile: https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/installation/docker.html

kartoza docker: https://github.com/kartoza/docker-geoserver

Both of them work on localhost.

I tried to deploy it onto AWS cloud. My infra is like this: CloudFront -> application load balancer (forward http to https listener)-> ECS GeoServer service.

The kartoza/geoserver works, and the https://my-domain.com/geoserver can hit ECS GeoServer service successfully.

However, the official GeoServer docker has redirect issues. In Chrome's inspect page, I can see network traffic redirects between web/? and web/?0, finally throw too many redirects error. Is there anyone running into the same issue on the official dockerfile? How to sort out?

Comment: Can you share the specific error you're getting? that way, people googling that error may end up here.

Comment: The error is thrown as too many redirects error.